# How do you call a Java method with two parameters from JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a JasperReports' jrxml file that contains calls of Java method code with one int parameter. All works well with the following code using a single parameter. **eventProjectid is an Integer**

```
<textField>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="250" y="79" width="103" height="15"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[com.rem40.reports.ReportUtils.getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequenceProject($F{eventProjectId})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

I need to introduce a second parameter which does not work, all I get is a null value back. Here is the jrxml code 
**eventProjectId is an Integer** and **eventType is a String**.

```
<textField>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="250" y="79" width="103" height="15"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[com.rem40.reports.ReportUtils.getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequenceProject($F{eventProjectId},$F{eventType})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Here is the Java code that I am trying to call

```
public static String getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequenceProject(Integer projectId, String eventType){
    ProjectEntity projectEntity = projectService.findById(projectId);

    CubeConfigEntity cubeConfigEntity=cubeConfigService.findByCubeTypeName(eventType,projectEntity.getCubeConfigName());
    if (cubeConfigEntity != null) {
        return cubeConfigEntity.getxAxisName();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Just to be clear I have tried to debug the call to no available. I believe there is an issue with how the method signature try to compare from the jrxml to the Java method. In debug the single parameter methods get called but the method with two parameters never gets called.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code is ok and you can call the method even with 10 parameters, it is just a Java. In case calling the method with wrong name you got the Exception. Right? `I need to introduce a second parameter which does not work, all I get is a null value back` - It means that: 1) maybe the logic of method is wrong. You can write a simple test (unit test) to check the logic  2) maybe the data came are not as you expected. You can check it with textFields 3) maybe you have the old version of jar in classpath. Recheck the version again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method

```
com.rem40.reports.ReportUtils.getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequenceProject()
```

has gone through two versions, right? One accepts a single integer argument, and the other version accepts an integer and a string as arguments.  Please double check that your japser report is pointing to the new version of the class file or library.

Also, please make sure that the two fields that you use, do have valid values with them

```
$F{eventProjectId}
$F{eventType}
```

Comment: I actually have two methods

Comment: Having multiple arguments should not be a problem, neither should having different signatures with same method name.  I think there must be something else that confused you.

Comment: I actually have two methods getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequence(Integer eventProjectId)  and another method  getCubeXAxisLabelMaxConsequenceProject(Integer eventProjectId, String eventType)       as for values both fields output there values as part of the report, so I know they are correct.  The singular argument works , it's just the two argument that does not.   Both method are in the same class file, so I know the correct path in being provided with the correct java classes.

Comment: Did you implement the two methods one by one?  Maybe your iReport is still referencing an old version that only has the single-argument method?

Comment: yes, my first implementation was with the one argument method call which still works in the output,  I then added another method the two argument one to the same java class file and even change the that method name in order to avoid a signature issue.   When I debug the code with breakpoints at each method the one method stops at the breakpoint, but the two argument method never breaks.  So I know the correct class file is being used.  I do a complete project build ever time just in case.

Comment: Try changing the name of the one-argument method to something else and see if your iReport can still call it.

Comment: leeyuiwah,  you were correct about the jar file.  Jasper studio froze and I had to use task manager to end the program.  Just for giggles I tried the debug again and everything worked including the two arg method.  I started up Jasper studio and then went and changed another method and it happened again.  Stopped Jasper studio, everything works.  I found out that jasper studio was putting an exclusive lock on the jar file so the ide could not replace the file when compiling.   Thanks for all your help